# AngularUI config state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using angularUI to configure a route like so:

```
    angular.module('adminui').config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider){

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $stateProvider
    .state('admin', {
      url: '/admin',
      templateUrl: 'vimes1984_foundation-angular-admin_client/templates/admin.ng.html',
      controller: 'adminCtrl'
    });
}]);
```

and I'm tring to configure the resolve in another config like so:

```
angular.module('yetibox').config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider){
    $stateProvider
    .state('admin', {
        resolve: {
              "currentUser": ["$meteor", function($meteor){
                return $meteor.requireUser();
              }]
            }
    });

}]);
```

but when I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module yetibox due to:
Error: State 'admin'' is already defined
```

How do I configure it across configs...

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Answer (score 0):

State need to be unique across an angualar application, regardless of the modules that are loaded. In your example, the module `adminui` defines a state called `admin` and so does the module `yetibox`.

So, it is not possible to configure a portion of a state in another module in the manner - it will try and create a new state.

The question would be why you would want to do this? From your question, you look to want to resolve the current user, to make it available to your `admin` state. This looks like a good case for using a state hierarchy. So something similar to:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('root', {
        abstract: true,
        resolve: {
              "currentUser": ["$meteor", function($meteor){
                return $meteor.requireUser();
              }]
            }
    })
    .state('root.admin', {
      url: '/admin',
      templateUrl: 'vimes1984_foundation-angular-admin_client/templates/admin.ng.html',
      controller: 'adminCtrl'
    });
```

Not that these states **can** be loaded in different modules quite safely.

If you're not keen on the 'dot' notation in the state names to denote hierarchy, you can use the `parent` property instead:

> No two states can have the same name. When using dot notation the
>   parent is inferred if it is not explicitly provided, but this doesn't
>   change the state name. When not using dot notation, the `parent` must be
>   explicitly provided, **but you still cannot name any two states the
>   same**, for example you can't have two different states named "edit"
>   even if they have different parents.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views